# How to Unit Test Windows Phone 8 MVVM Async Commands?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to write some unit test for some Commands in My ViewModel Class.
I want to test the execution of an **ICommand**.

My **ICommand.Execute()** method executes an **async** method.

how can I write a test case for this command ?

Note: I'm using The Windows Phone Unit Test framework delivered in CTP2 of Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/01/31/windows-phone-unit-tests-in-visual-studio-2012-update-2.aspx

Comment: Even though this isn't for the Unit Test framework delivered in VS2012 CTP2, here's how to support async test methods in the more widely used Silverlight Unit Testing framework @ http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2012/12/21/Hacking-the-Silverlight-Unit-Tests-to-support-returning-Task.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It's much easier to test `async Task` methods; that is, have your `async void Execute` implementation just `await` an `async Task` method, which is the one that's actually unit tested.

The built-in MSTest unit test framework does not support testing `async void` methods, since it's a bit involved and would raise backwards-compatibility issues. Currently, NUnit is the only unit testing framework that supports `async void` methods.

If you really want to test an `async void` method and don't want to use NUnit, you can use [Stephen Toub's `AsyncPump`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/02/10263555.aspx) or [my `AsyncContext`](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncContext) (available on NuGet) to create your own context for each unit test. In this case, your test will look something like:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMyAsyncVoidMethod()
{
  ICommand myCommand = ...;

  AsyncContext.Run(() =>
  {
    myCommand.Execute();
    Assert.IsTrue(command-is-in-progress);
  });

  Assert.IsTrue(command-completed);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume you'd tag the method with the `[Asynchronous]` attribute and then just call `await ICommand.Execute()`

Check [this post](http://www.smartypantscoding.com/a-cheat-sheet-for-unit-testing-silverlight-apps-on-windows-phone-7) for a sample of asynchronous Windows Phone method testing.

Comment: I tried to add [Asynchronous], but it's namespace cannot be resolved, what Assemblies do I have to reference ?

Answer (score 0):

You should change your test method signature to

`[TestMethod]
public async Task TestMyAsyncVoidMethod()
{....`

So that you can await you command execute method.